Secrets Manager structure in AWS
I want to start using secrets manager in my business, but I have a question concerning the structure.
should I create a unique value per secret? or should I use one secret per platform? example:
Website secret containing all my website secrets, Mobile application that contains all user secrets, etc...
I tried looking at some documents, but I found no advice or help concerning this topic.

It really depends on

frequency of access to these secrets,
Rotation Policy

I would be as granular as you can since secrets manager will manage the inventory and document your process and conventions.


Once per run
Not very frequently rotated


I would implement tagging if you begin getting an unwieldy amount of secrets but it sounds like you'll be fine with a slow rotation and once per run implementation of secrets.
